# Javers: transaction ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

I want to create a Rollback functionality that will based on Javers audit. So my case: I have to save a list of entities ("Person") and I have to rollback this action due to some issue. I need to mark this transaction in Javers to find all the changed entities and roll back them regarding their revision.

Javers supports rollback functionality by the certain record but I need to select and rollback the whole group of entities.

Does Javers have such functionality or a workaround? Or maybe any ideas on how can I implement it.